# How to make resizable li elements with CSS only

Tags: css, list, html-lists

Scenario: I have an unordered list **< ul >** of width (lets say 200px) with four **< li >** elements that are sized equally. Therefore each should be 50px. When I add a 5th **< li >** element each width should re-size to 40px. If I change the width of the **< ul >** to 500px with 5 **< li >** elements, each **< li >** element should be 100px.

**Is this possible with only CSS? If yes, how is it implemented?**

*Currently, I have a solution that meets the above requirements but it includes jQuery to re-size the **< li >** elements based on mathematical calculations.*

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: @halfdan - accept them when they make sense and work

Comment: @NAVEED - i'm hoping for some sort of liquid resizable solution

Comment: @NAVEED, sadly not. Yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aparently you can fake tables like [here](http://dizque.lacalabaza.net/temp/full-width-navigation-bar-with-css.html), but I am not sure if this works in all browsers(edit: it works on winxp ie8, chrome 7, firefox).

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="...">...</a>
        </li>
        <!-- other list items -->
    </ul>
</div>

#menu {
    display: table;
}

ul {
    display: table-row;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Also example on fiddle.net [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kDcZ6/)

Comment: Confirmed on winXP and Safari 4 ... and +1, I'm impressed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't completely make sense to me.  If you leave the `width`s off, the list will be as wide as it needs to be.  But here's a crack at your question:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
ul
{
  width:500px;
}
li
{
  width:100px;
}
</style>

<ul>
  <li>1. one</li>
  <li>2. two</li>
  <li>3. three</li>
  <li>4. four</li>
  <li>5. five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: He's saying he wants the list to be a fixed width and the items to all take an equal portion of that list no matter how how many items there are. Essentially, `ul li { width: (numberOfListItems/100)% ;}`.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS expressions it is possible, but CSS Expressions come with a very heavy performance penalty. JavaScript (and jQuery for that matter) is the appropriate tool to use to create the effect you want.

CSS should only be used for styling, HTML should only be used for structure, and JavaScript should be used whenever you want to create *dynamic* content.

Answer (score 0):

Until such a time as browsers implement the [`calc()`, `min()` and `max()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-values/#the-calc-min-and-max-functions) functions this isn't possible outside of scripting (either server-, or client-, side) or using a table.

Currently, and surprisingly (perhaps only to me), neither [Firefox](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/comment-page-1/), [Webkit or Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)) support `calc()` function, not even with the various flavours of vendor prefix.

That said, one day something like the following *might* work (but not today, sadly):

```
ul {
  counter-reset: numListItems;
  width: 60%;
}

ul li {
  counter-increment: numListItems;
  width: calc(100%/numListItems);
}
```

But, obviously, for *that* to work browsers would need to implement some form, and understanding, of variables within the scope of `calc()`, which doesn't appear to be necessarily on the road-map (I'm not sure that the `counter()` is, or is intended to be, interoperable with the `calc()`).